# I cannot run jhipster application using the latest jhipster version 3.0

Tags: jhipster

I'm using the new version of jhipster 3.0 , I created a jhipster application and when I run my application I had no error but no thing was displayed on my browser I cannot understand the problem.

I import my application to intellij and I run it from intellij.
Here is what I get in the intellij run console:

```
 2016-03-25 01:39:33.675 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Enter: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=Fri Mar 25 01:39:33 GMT-08:00 2016, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]] 2016-03-25 01:39:33.736 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Exit: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with result = null 2016-03-25 01:39:34.094 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.l.t.s.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access 2016-03-25 01:39:39.922 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Enter: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=Fri Mar 25 01:39:39 GMT-08:00 2016, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]]2016-03-25 01:39:39.923 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Exit:org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with result = null 2016-03-25 01:39:39.923 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.l.t.s.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access 2016-03-25 02:03:14.549 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Enter: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=Fri Mar 25 02:03:11 GMT-08:00 2016, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]]2016-03-25 02:03:15.076 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Exit: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with result = null
2016-03-25 02:03:15.620 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.l.t.s.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2016-03-25 02:03:21.547 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Enter: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=Fri Mar 25 02:03:21 GMT-08:00 2016, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]]
2016-03-25 02:03:21.548 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Exit: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with result = null
2016-03-25 02:03:21.549 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] c.l.t.s.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2016-03-25 02:03:31.991 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Enter: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=Fri Mar 25 02:03:31 GMT-08:00 2016, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]]
2016-03-25 02:03:31.992 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Exit: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with result = null
2016-03-25 02:03:31.992 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] c.l.t.s.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2016-03-25 02:03:39.009 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Enter: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=Fri Mar 25 02:03:39 GMT-08:00 2016, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]]
2016-03-25 02:03:39.009 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Exit: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with result = null
2016-03-25 02:03:39.010 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] c.l.t.s.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2016-03-25 02:03:43.700 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Enter: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=Fri Mar 25 02:03:43 GMT-08:00 2016, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]]
2016-03-25 02:03:43.701 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Exit: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with result = null
2016-03-25 02:03:43.701 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.l.t.s.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2016-03-25 02:03:48.072 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Enter: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=Fri Mar 25 02:03:48 GMT-08:00 2016, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]]
2016-03-25 02:03:48.072 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Exit: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with result = null
2016-03-25 02:03:48.073 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] c.l.t.s.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2016-03-25 02:03:51.393 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Enter: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=Fri Mar 25 02:03:51 GMT-08:00 2016, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]]
2016-03-25 02:03:51.393 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Exit: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with result = null
2016-03-25 02:03:51.421 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] c.l.t.s.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2016-03-25 02:05:13.542 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Enter: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=Fri Mar 25 02:05:13 GMT-08:00 2016, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]]
2016-03-25 02:05:13.543 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Exit: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with result = null
2016-03-25 02:05:13.544 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] c.l.t.s.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
2016-03-25 02:05:19.580 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Enter: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with argument[s] = [AuditEvent [timestamp=Fri Mar 25 02:05:19 GMT-08:00 2016, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]]
2016-03-25 02:05:19.581 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.lyance.test.aop.logging.LoggingAspect : Exit: org.springframework.boot.actuate.audit.AuditEventRepository.add() with result = null
2016-03-25 02:05:19.582 DEBUG 3220 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.l.t.s.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
```

here is the code of `.yo-rc.json` file :

```
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
"jhipsterVersion": "3.0.0",
"baseName": "test2",
"packageName": "com.lyance.test",
"packageFolder": "com/lyance/test",
"serverPort": "8080",
"authenticationType": "oauth2",
"hibernateCache": "ehcache",
"clusteredHttpSession": "no",
"websocket": "spring-websocket",
"databaseType": "sql",
"devDatabaseType": "postgresql",
"prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
"searchEngine": "no",
"buildTool": "maven",
"useSass": true,
"applicationType": "monolith",
"testFrameworks": [
  "gatling"
],
"enableTranslation": true,
"nativeLanguage": "fr",
"languages": [
  "fr"
]
  }
}
```

npm install & bower install :

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency / chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture : fsevents@1.0.9
```

Comment: Downvoted as no details given as usual, please learn how to ask for help on jhipster as I already asked you for previous questions. Error in browser console,?.yo-rc.json file, how did you run app (mvn only or mvn+gulp), error in npm install or bower install?

Comment: I imported my jhipster project to  intellij, then I run it without any compilation errors, but every time I put the url of my application ( http://127.0.0.1:8080 ) in the browser  no thing was displayed except the famous word "footer", and I get the code  above in the intellij console.

Comment: again provide what I asked in comment above

Comment: So sorry @GaëlMarziou I edited my question , I hope it's more clear now

Answer (score 0):

From your `.yo-rc.json` file, I can see that you use SASS, it's probable that CSS were not generated, try running `gulp sass`.

Also for your dev workflow, you should consider running both maven and gulp as explained in the doc (Using the Java server and Gulp together): https://jhipster.github.io/development/

Comment: I tried to do what did you say but still have the same problem,I had in my browser console the error " Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" for:  i18n/angular-locale_en.js, i18n/en/global.json, i18n/en/home.json and api/account?cacheBuster=1459203067183

Comment: It's not the same problem as you never mentioned these errors before

Comment: I used your `.yo-rc.json` file with a small difference `"devDatabaseType": "h2Memory"` and it works perfeclty. So I suspect something wrong in your environment either in node or in postgres. What does display `node --version`, what is your OS? Could you edit your  `.yo-rc.json` file as I did and re-run `yo jhipster`?

Comment: I don't think the problem is with postgres because the database is generated correctly (My OS is windows 7 , the version of Node.js is 5.9.1)

Comment: OK, then you're not using a LTS version of node which is what we recommend.

Comment: BTW, the test that I ran with h2 database is valid, it's just that I did not want to setup a postgres db just for this. So it's clearly a problem of environment or the way you build and run your app. Have you tried running it outside IntelliJ following our doc?

Comment: I installed the LTS version of node.js instide of the Node.js 5.9.1 , and I tried to run the project outside intellig ( mvn spring-boot:run) but I had the same problem. These problem can't be related to the browser??

Comment: No I don't think so, it's probably related to some errors during either generation phase that you did not see or during build/run. In your project, delete `node_modules` and `src\main\webapp\bower_components` folders, then run `npm install` and `bower install`, if no error then run `mvn` and `gulp` commands

Comment: Final check, I suppose that this is a project that you generated from scratch using Jhipster 3.x and not a project that you upgraded from JHipster 2.27.x, correct?

Comment: This is not a project that I upgraded.I just installed the new jhipster version 3.0.0 and then I simply created a project.

Comment: I did all you said but no thing change, I still having an empty page

Comment: OK, I've spent too much time on this, so either you use our devbox https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-devbox or you recognize that you don't have the skills to debug this issue and either you abandon JHipster or you train yourself on node, angular and spring boot.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! I solved it !! It was a problem in the file translation-storage.provider.js

Comment: Could you clarify what was the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hello @chouchato and @gaël-marziou 
Recently, I've had to face the chouchato's error too. And I took considerable time to find a way to fix it. How the error did no sense for me, I did those (many) steps like trial and error and then the problem doesn't appeared again:

npm = 3.8.9
node = 5.9.0

1) Update NPM 
2) Update all npm packages to LTS versions 
3) Update yoeman package too (now 1.8.1) 
4) Follow @gaël-marziou's advise: delete directory node_modules/ and bower_components/ 
5) I had to run `npm rebuild` to recompile packages C++ for Sass 
6) Ran `npm install & bower install`

That is it. Everything is working like a charm now.